# href sms being omitted inside the mailchimp editor after saving

Tags: html, mailchimp

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask since my question involves code. I'm trying to place an sms link inside the email template. After the user taps on the anchor element it will open the SMS app within there phones.

`<a href="sms:09153696254" >09153696254</a>`

After placing the code, saving the changes within the editor, mailchimp removes the href attribute within the anchor element. I've attached an image as reference

[image]

I tried looking for answer but it seems it's not a common question

Comment: I've never heard about a `sms` protocol

Comment: Tried different methods or alternatives but keeps removing the code where it enables opening a SMS app

Comment: So I did a test with my MC account, and you are correct! The href disappears on saving. This might be intentional. I am chatting with them now.

Comment: @clestcruz did this answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

After checking with Mailchimp, I can confirm that this tag:

```
<a href = "sms://+01111111">send a text</a>
```

does NOT work with Mailchimp, and that currently, you can use `tel:` and `mailto:` but that is it. The `sms:` is partly a no-no because of the risk of unsolicited texts. Perhaps place a body of text saying `text (SOMENUMBER) for more info`?